# react i18next file override issue in microfrontend

Tags: react-i18next

Iam facing issue in integrating react-i18next with micro frontend. Each micro app has react-i18next dep and its loading its resource file async way. When traversing b/w app using react Link Router, it is overriding other resource file or picking other app resource file

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Did you find any solution for this or any other library?